# Ajax running and inserting row data many times after button press in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on AJAX and PHP PDO to insert a post and display it by ajax without reloading the page. I have an issue, when I click on the post button the message inserts one time and displays. It's a good process but after that when I add the new message and click on the post button the message inserts 2 times in the database and displays the same two times. Same when I create a new message again the message inserts four times (I think ajax running many times after the first insertion ) but if I refresh the page and enter a new message the message inserts and displays one time. That's good but I don't want to refresh for every entry.
AJAX code -

```
   $(document).on("click", "#save", function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
                var message = $("#message").val();
                 var form_data = new FormData();
                form_data.append('message', message);
            
        var property = document.getElementById('photo').files;
         property = property[0];
if(property){
    var image_name = property.name;
    var image_extension = image_name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    form_data.append("file",property);
}

var propertyv = document.getElementById('video').files;
         propertyv = propertyv[0];
if(propertyv){
    var name = propertyv.name;
    var extension = name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    form_data.append("video",propertyv);
}
                //Ajax call to send data to the insert.php
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "insert_posts.php",
                    data: form_data,
                   contentType:false,
          cache:false,
          processData:false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        
                         $(data).insertAfter(".message-wrap:first");
                       
                        $("#message").val("");
                           $("#photo").val('');
                           $("#video").val('');

                              $('#body-bottom').hide();
                              $('#body-bottom-video').hide();
                                 $("#form")[0].reset();
                             

                    }
                });
            });
```

[image: Issue Screenshot]

You can see the image above the first message is inserting one time but if I create a new second message and click on the post button it inserts two times then same for - 4, 8 times for the next entries.
I don't want to refresh and the second message should be inserted one time like the first message.

More details -
The ajax code is in another JS file . I have inked to index.php page

```
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
```

Comment: sounds like your calling the above script again and its calling `$(document).on("click", "#save",` again, restucture your code or call `off('click')` etc

Comment: Ok, but how to check it. I have updated PHP scripts also. Can you please check and answer?

Comment: Please share more details, and your debugging attempts. Is this even related to PHP, if the error happens solely in your browser through duplicated JS events?

Comment: if its in `<script src="ajax.js"></script>` then yeah, its going to invoke it again once the dom loads as your returning it each time in the response

Comment: PHP is working cool for the first entry without a page refresh but if for the second entry it enters two times in two rows and display two times. I mean the same message in two columns. No errors from SERVER for PHP.

Comment: Yes i have in <script src="ajax.js"></script> but what is the best way to do it ? In same php file or other thing .

Comment: move it out of the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one() method is useful for every event type.
I have changed the line above

```
 $(document).one("click", "#save", function (e)
```

Now, it's working.

For more reference - https://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

try add e.stopPropagation(); after e.preventDefault();

Comment: I have added in ajax.js after e.preventDefault();
           e.stopPropagation(); but, its not working . Same issue occured .